# May good health envelop you, spurring a quick recovery

Tags: metaphors, figurative-language, greetings

Is there anything wrong with the following sentence?
Is the metaphor "envelop you" used correctly?

> May good health envelop you, spurring a quick recovery.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It's understandable, but I've never heard anyone wish another person good health in that way!

Comment: I've found examples of joy enveloping a person.

Comment: Apart from that, is there anything ungrammatical about the original sentence?

Comment: No - it's just a very unusual and high-flown way of wishing someone a speedy recovery!

Comment: Unusual indeed. Some common phrases border on being cliches. I guess that's why the author cast the expression that way. How about "May Peace & Joy envelop you and your loved ones"?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/kvsongs/photos/a.366127454169/10157129879499170/?type=3